# Python Seaborn swarmplot order of the dodge

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, swarmplot

In Seaborn, I am looking to define the order in which the hue variables are presented when using the dodge functionality.

Using the [seaborn swarmplot documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html) documentation as an example, in the plot where dodge is explained, they show smoker (green) on the left and non-smoker (orange) on the right.  How can I control that order?  I would like non-smoker on the left and smoker on the right.

The example code
does not specify and seems to leave it up to the format of the data:

```
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, palette="Set2", dodge=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the argument `hue_order`:

```
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", hue_order=["No", "Yes"], 
                    data=tips, palette="Set2", dodge=True)
```

[image]

Note that this does not swap the colours around.

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed that and found it around the same time you posted.